# Handling double quotes in parameter with @Query annotation

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a query implemented in my Elastic Search repository using the `@Query` annotation. One of the fields in the query is a String and I found that when I attempt to execute the query using a parameter that has double quotes in it, the query fails to parse.

It appears that the `ElasticsearchStringQuery:88` class simply does a replacement of the parameter value into the string query without escaping possible quotes in the parameter. Am I doing something wrong or is this just a known limitation? If it is known, it seems odd that the caller must escape the quotes in the parameter before executing the finder method on the repository. This causes my code to be littered with double quote stripping or escaping and it leaks the query format externally (i.e. that double quotes are used to define the query and therefore can't be used in parameters).

An example query:

```
@Query("{  \"filtered\" : { \"query\" : { \"bool\" : { \"must\" : [ {  \"match\" : { \"programTitle\" : { \"query\" : \"?0\",  \"type\" : \"boolean\",              \"operator\" : \"AND\", \"fuzziness\" : \"0\" } } }, { \"match\" : {            \"title\" : { \"query\" : \"?2\", \"type\" : \"boolean\", \"operator\" : \"AND\",\"fuzziness\" : \"0\"  }  } } ] } },    \"filter\" : { \"term\" : {        \"programAirDate\" : \"?1\"  }  }  }}")
```

The query is being executed with the test case:

```
repository.save(piece);
List<Piece> actual = repository.findByProgramTitleAndProgramAirDateAndTitle(
    piece.getProgramTitle(),
    airDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT),
    piece.getTitle(), new PageRequest(0, 1));
```

If `piece.getTitle()` contains double quotes such as with *Franz Joseph Haydn: String Quartet No. 53 "The Lark"*, the query fails with the error:

```
at [Source: [B@1696066a; line: 1, column: 410]]; }{[7x1Q86yNTdy0a0zHarqYVA][metapub][4]: SearchParseException[[metapub][4]: from[0],size[1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":1,"query_binary":"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"}]]]; 
nested: QueryParsingException[[metapub] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
```

Decoding the base64 query I can see that the double quotes are causing the issue:

```
... "title" : { "query" : "Franz Joseph Haydn: String Quartet No. 53 "The Lark"", "type" : "boolean", "operator" : "AND", ...
```

I can make things work by removing all the double quotes (for example, `piece.getTitle().replaceAll("\"", "")`) but that seems like something the framework should handle. When using a JDBC repository, the user doesn't have to remove/replace special characters because the JDBC driver does it automatically.

So what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Since Communication is using JSON, YOU must provide a valid JSON String. 
This means, it is your responsibility to escape the double quotes

Comment: I can understand that the JSON in the @Query annotation must be valid JSON but forcing the user of the repository to escape double quotes seems problematic. It is going back to the days of SQL injection when the user of JDBC needed to escape characters manually. It seems like the parameter replacement logic should handle escaping invalid characters automatically but I guess that isn't the case with the ES module.

Comment: To make things even worse, it wasn't even enough from me to escape them once. If I wanted to add a `@Query` method param with a quote in it, like `"\"something"`, it didn't work, escaping it a second time: `"\\\"something"` didn't work either, I had to escape it for a THIRD time: `"\\\\\\\\"something"`. That's very weird and frustrating. No idea why Spring Data Elastic behaves like this. And yes, inserting params into a query without checking or escaping is going back to the SQL injection days...